# React js.Changing button colours if user clicked on correct/incorrect options from API

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React js so please show mercy... I would like to change the color of buttons{options} when the user clicked on the correct/incorrect answer from API based on my code. I don't know how I can connect this... I appreciate any help.

```
useEffect(()=>{
axios
.get("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1")
.then(res => {
 setQuestions
(res.data.results.map((questionItem,index)=>{
const answer =decodeString(questionItem.correct_answer)
const options=[...questionItem.incorrect_answers.map(decodeString),answer]

return{
id:`${index}-${Date.now()}`,
question:decodeString(questionItem.question),
answer:answer ,
options:options.sort(() =>Math.random() - .5)}} ))})}, [])

  return (

 <div className="question-container">
  <div >
  <h1>{countQuestion} Question</h1>
  </div>

  <div className='item-container'>
    {questions.map((questions) => (
      <div className="question-display" key={questions.id}>
        <h3>{questions.question}</h3>

        <div className="options-display">
{questions.options.map(options => {
 return <button className="btn-option" key={options}>{options}</button>
   })}

        </div>

        <div className="show-answers">
        <button onClick={()=>setShow(!show)} >Show Answer</button>

        <div className="answer">
       {show ? <h1>{questions.answer}</h1>:null}
        </div>
<div className="btn-next-container">
<button onClick={nextQuestion}>Next</button>
</div>
        </div>
      </div>))}
  </div>
</div>
 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this code in such a way that it assigns a class name simply by checking whether an option is clicked.

Hope this code helps.

```
// An array that checks if the option in question with that number is clicked
const [isClick, setIsClick] = useState([]);

// button click function
  const handleOption = () => {
    if (isClick[countQuestion - 1]) return;
    let newdata = [...isClick];
    newdata[countQuestion - 1] = true;
    setIsClick(newdata);
  };

// questions map
<div className="options-display">
   {questions.options.map((options) => {
       return (
          <button
             className={`btn-option ${
                  isClick[countQuestion - 1]
                  ? options === questions.answer? "correct" : "incorrect"
                  : ""
                }`}
                key={options}
                onClick={handleOption}
              >
               {options}
              </button>
             );
           })}
</div>
```

Comment: It does work.You have no idea how much you helped me in my development!Thank u so much! I appreciate it :)